# C# Application launch new revision delete all content

Tags: c#, file, updates, revision

I have a problem, I save the user information of my application in an XML file, every time I update my version this XML file is removed. The file is located under application folder \XML\

Is there any way to keep this files during revision upgrades?

Comment: Store it on the %APPDATA% folder, is designed specifically for this.

Comment: There must be some sort of install/update process you've put in place that's overwriting it?

Comment: @Gusman Write that as answer so I can up-vote it..of course explain why though too.

Answer (score 3):

The application folder should not contain any user data, the application folder should contain only the program files, precissely because of this, to avoid data deletion when the user reinstalls or upgrades the app.

Windows has a folder specifically designed to store application data, it's accessed through `%APPDATA%` if you're on the OS (explorer and so on) and from C# you can access it with `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`.

There are also LocalApplicationData and CommonApplicationData, you can search info about those folders to understand the specific usage of each one.